# How Widely Used is Polkit?

Tags: linux, privileges, polkit

I'm writing a program that requires root access. I'm hoping to use `polkit` for privilege escalation instead of just erroring out when the program is not run from root or via sudo.

Is polkit used on all major linux distributions? If not, is there some other generic way to ask for privilege escalation on linux?

---

Is polkit the only way do do this?:

[image]

Comment: You mean like `sudo`?

Comment: @terdon Asking user for escalation if the user doesn't have permissions and didn't use sudo. For example, try stopping/starting a service with `systemctl` without sudo

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something like `[ $(id -u) = 1 ] && command || sudo command`. It depends on how much of your program needs elevated privileges. If all of it, you could just have a wrapper script that runs `[ $(id -u) = 1 ] && your_program || sudo your_program`. On the other hand, I know nothing about polkit and it may very well be the better solution (hence this comment instead of an answer).

Comment: I'd prefer not to have my program run itself as a subprocess, since that is a can of worms with regard to control-flow(sending keyboard interrupts, etc), however I might end up doing like you suggest if there is no other guaranteed way getting permissions.

Comment: @BryceGuinta:  Since it's your program and you apparently want it to run as root all the time, why don't you setuid it to root?

Comment: making allowances for users too lazy or forgetful to use `sudo` (or whatever) when appropriate is an even bigger can of worms.  just check for euid != 0 and exit with "root privs required" error message.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Doesn't that just give a permission error if you aren't already root?

Comment: @BryceGuinta:  In your program, add `setuid(0);` near the beginning and once compiled, `chown root program; chmod 4755 program;`

Comment: @cas That might be the easiest solution for now. I do admire programs that are user friendly though

Comment: @JuliePelletier Wow - just tried it. I didn't know that was possible.